# How to split multiple dataframes, reform them into new dataframes, and then save as csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I have lots of dataframes(Please note that "code" is index, lengths of these dataframes are not necessarily the same, and to be brief I set the number of dataframes as 2)

```
volume:
            20200101  20200102 ... 20200630     
code  001      1          2    ...     3  
      002      2          na    ...    4
      ...
      997      2          1    ...     8
      999      4          5    ...     6

price:
            20200101  20200102 ... 20200630     
code  001      10        12    ...    30  
      002      na         2    ...    4
      ...
      997      4          5    ...    6
```

My ideal result is to multiple csv files which include data of each day, and transform corresponding dataframe into csv files named by each "date" within the given period, for example file named as "20200101" is:

```
           volume      price
code  001    1           10
      002    2           na
      ...
      997    2           4
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that each column name is a date in your data frame as per the examples you have provided.

```
dfList = [df1, df2, ...]    # List of dataframes

columns = df1.columns().to_list()   #Columns that are to be exported as separate csv

for col in columns:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for eachDF in dfList:
        df = df.append(eachDF[col])
    df.to_csv(f'{col}.csv')
```

Comment: 'Index' object is not callable

Comment: it seems to be "columns = df1.columns.to_list()"